# CMake C++/C++CLI/C# VS solution build applocal.ps1 fail

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmake, c++-cli, vcpkg

I have a simple CMake C++/C++CLI/C# VS solution that is intended to test interoperability between C++ and C#. I used VS2017 15.9.18 and CMake3.14.0-rc2.

Everything seems to work fine but while building the C# project, the output log complains :

```
C:\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\msbuild\applocal.ps1:60
dumpbin : The term 'dumpbin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
+     $a = $(dumpbin /DEPENDENTS $targetBinary | ? { $_ -match "^    [^ ...
+            ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dumpbin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Since I have very little knowledge about how vcpkg and CMake work, I don't even know whether if this would cause serious problems in the later stage. According to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues/557) issue, it seems like vcpkg does not have dumpbin on the path while building csproj. What is the exact cause of it and how to solve it?

Comment: I could bypass the problem by replacing dumpbin to the exact path of dumpbin.exe but I think the implementation should be changed so that C# projects can have PATH set normally as C++ projects do.

Answer (score 0):

If you have VS installed in your system, please use **Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio** instead of regular command prompt,